# Can I make a symlink point to different locations on different machines?

Tags: mount, symlink, sshfs, file-server

Before you say "no", a workaround would also be fine.

Here is the situation: I have two machines `local` and `compile`, both including the same `~` over nfs from a third machine `files`. I would like to have a directory on `compile:/opt/foo/` instead of `files:~/foo/` for speed. But I want to still be able to work from `local` without having to work on a different path.

I can sshfs mount `compile:/opt/foo/` locally on `local:~/compile/opt/foo/` but if I want to have one directory at the same path **inside my `~`** on both machines, symlinks don't seem to cut it, as they want to point at the same path.

Is there a solution for this problem that enables me to have my files sitting on the local drive of `compile` instead of the nfs mount?

Note: I cannot gain root privileges on any of these machines.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to do a double symlink similar to what `/etc/alternatives` does on Ubuntu namely:

Inside `~` you will have a link:

```
linked_directory -> /<local filesystem>/linked_directory
```

On each of the local machines:

```
/<local filesystem>/linked_directory -> /<actual location>/linked_directory
```

As long as neither `/<local filesystem>/` nor `/<actual location>/` are shared between machines inside your `~` the contents of `linked_directory` will be unique.

Comment: I think he has no root privileges, which means he cannot step outside of his home directory (a link in /tmp would be problematic).

Comment: @January There is also `/var/tmp` and possibly other local directories OP has access to.  Besides someone did set up `/opt/foo` as a mountpoint for the OP(*cringe*), which does require root privileges.

Comment: Well, sure, if the administrator does that, that would definitely be the easiest solution!

Comment: @Karlson: Actually it's `compile:/opt/<username>/`. Why is that *cringe*-worthy?

Comment: @bitmask Because generally `/opt` is meant for optional software installation not user's home directories.  A better practice is to have software developed, tested, in `/home/<user>` and once the software is done you make it read only and put in `/opt/` or `/usr/local`, so that people don't have an option to fat-finger things

Comment: @Karlson: Well, it's a compile and evaluation server and `/home/<user>/` is slow because it's an nfs mount, so it makes sense to have a local persistent (unlike `/tmp`) location. Maybe `/srv/` would've been a better choice but that's mounted to the projects directory. I agree that users should stay in their `~` in general, but in this situation I don't see how that could have been achieved.

Comment: @bitmask That's a different discussion altogether...

Answer (score 2):

Symlinks will not help, since they are written to the filesystem -- and so they will always be the same on both machines.

However, if your administrator installed bindfs, you can mount different things on both machines. For example, on `local`, you use sshfs to mount `compile:/opt/foo/` with `~/foo/` as the mount point. On `compile`, you use bindfs to mount `/opt/foo/` with `~/foo/` as your mount point:

```
bindfs -n /opt/foo ~/foo
```

Comment: +1 for the suggestion, but `compile` doesn't seem to have `bindfs` installed.

Comment: @bitmask If you have SSHFS, you have FUSE. Enabling FUSE requires privileges, but installing additional filesystems such as Bindfs doesn't, you can do it.